# Where to add content type for firefox os packged app

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firefox-os

I have developed small game and uploaded it to for review, But it got rejected for having mistakes in my app manifest.

**This is the message i got from reviewers:**

Your app cannot be installed because your server is serving the manifest with an invalid content type - it should be Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json.

**My app URL for testing**: curl -I -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; rv:18.0) Gecko/18.0 Firefox/18.0" https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/magic-colors/

Please suggest me where i should ad proper content type, since this is packaged app there is no .htaccess file or i have to create one.

Comment: you don't have to host package apps yourself, you upload them as a zip file to the marketplace. content type is required only for hosted apps.

Comment: I have uploaded zip file only, but after review I got the above message

Comment: I do not think you should be getting this error for a packaged app.  For a hosted app: https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Apps/Manifest#Serving_manifests .  BTW your app ran fine for me.

Comment: @Jason can you please suggest me what I have to do next, I have to update the app again to marketplace

Comment: I am checking with the marketplace team.  You did want the app to be packaged correct?  Meaning not hosted on your own site.

Comment: I don't want to host, since this is game there won't be updates to app. Thanks for your quick reply and help

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem has been fixed as your application has been published into the marketplace yesterday. In your case, I don't know what was the problem as it was a packaged application, but for anyone with a hosted application, if you got this kind of error from the marketplace reviewer team

> Your app cannot be installed because your server is serving the
>   manifest with an invalid content type - it should be Content-Type:
>   application/x-web-app-manifest+json.

Please check [how you serve the manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#Serving_manifests) file from your server.

Comment: @Harper Yes my app got published. Thanks for your suggestion.